# ARKit - AR using ultra wide camera 0.5 on iPhone 13 Pro

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

Goal:
An AR app using the ultra wide camera 0.5 on iPhone 13 Pro.

Tried:
The documentation is very scarce, and shows only how to switch between front or back camera, but does not give an option to select which camera:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/choosing_which_camera_feed_to_augment
:
Is it possible to have an ARView on the ultra wide camera 0.5 on iPhone 13 Pro?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/videoformat/3738412-capturedevicetype), it appears that yes you can use the “ultra-wide camera in a face-tracking session”. You’ll need to loop through the supported video formats (see linked example code) to check if your device supports that format, or any others you may want to use.